# Docker build fails with the current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

Doing this on windows 10:

```
>docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
Building MyApprestapi
Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
 ---> 6237a4750408
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
Removing intermediate container ae0057e8752c
 ---> d422fca6b533
Step 3/17 : EXPOSE 11001
 ---> Running in 70f6f9a9d052
Removing intermediate container 70f6f9a9d052
 ---> 673d1c1d8f34
Step 4/17 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
 ---> f5f1d9a332af
Step 5/17 : WORKDIR /src
Removing intermediate container 0c5e68914dfd
 ---> 035e0d5467bf
Step 6/17 : COPY MyAppPipeline.sln ./
 ---> b0ccbf6431b4
Step 7/17 : COPY MyAppRestApi/MyAppRestApi.csproj MyAppRestApi/
 ---> 3216ad77f880
Step 8/17 : RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
 ---> Running in f0b9fa8dbbd4
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. [C:\src\MyAppRestApi\MyAppRestApi.csproj]
ERROR: Service 'MyApprestapi' failed to build: The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

And if I do:

```
>dotnet --info
```

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   2.1.300 
>   Commit:    adab45bf0c
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.17134 
>   OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 2.1.0   Commit:  caa7b7e2ba
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0
>   [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   1.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.3 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Answer (score 5):

The problem was my DockerFile which was generated at the time of project creation.
I had to use the replacements listed here:

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker

```
microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
```